# How to read text file and write to dataframe rows more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading lines from a text file and writing the desired data to rows in a pandas dataframe. The following code (simplified) works, but does not seem very computationally efficient:

```
    with open(DataFile, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.strip().split("\t")
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.append(df.values, [data], axis=0))
```

I have also tried this, but this even slower:

```
    with open(DataFile, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            i += 1
            data = line.strip().split("\t")
            df.loc[i] = data
```

Is there a more computationally efficient way to do this? Potentially pre-allocating memory for the dataframe?

Comment: DataFrames have lots of read_XYZ methods for ingesting files.

Comment: you can simply use the pandas function for reading csv files `pd.read_csv(filename)`, given the sturcture of what you're trying to read. Would be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try read tab-separated file by [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv):

```
df = pandas.read_csv(DataFile, sep='\t', lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. If my datafile contains a few header lines, how can I start reading the file after the header information?

Comment: @Tony pandas will try to read headers automatically, but there's `skiprows=` parameter (see the documentation). You can specify list of row numbers to skip (0-indexed) or just number - that's how many rows are skipped from the beginning.